# new_menu() fails when then menu has an odd number of items (!=1)

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses

I'm trying to create a menu in ncurses and the number of items in the menu can change on every call to my function, but if I run this when I have (3,5) unique items in the menu, I get a crash and gdb gives me this:
`_nc_Connect_Items error ncurses _nc_Connect_Items (menu=menu@entry=0x5555555f2830, items=items@entry=0x5555555e0b70) at ../menu/m_global.c:185`
I can post full output if needed.

Another problem I have is the description string in the menu being the same as last item, but maybe it's WAI. Could not find it in the docs at https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/.

So here's the code:

```
...
            
    WINDOW *my_wins[1];
    ITEM **my_items;
    MENU *my_menu;
        WINDOW *my_menu_win;
        int n_choices = 0;
    int c;
    
    /* Initialize curses */
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "uk_UK.UTF-8");
    initscr();
    clear();
    refresh();
    start_color();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);


    /* Initialize all the colors */
    init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(3, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(4, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(5, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(6, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(7, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_WHITE);
    init_pair(8, COLOR_MAGENTA, COLOR_BLACK);
    
    //To print something when you have no consumables

    for (int i = 0; i < CONSUMABLESMAX +1; i++) {
        Consumable * c = &consumablesBag[i];
        int q = c->qty;
        if (q > 0) {
            n_choices++;
        }
    }

    if (n_choices == 0) {
            
        my_menu_win = newwin(10, 40, 2, 2);
            
        box(my_menu_win, 0, 0);
                
        wattron(my_menu_win,COLOR_PAIR(6));
        mvwprintw(my_menu_win,2, 2, "Your bag is empty.");
        mvwprintw(my_menu_win,3, 2, "You'll find more consumables soon.");
        wattroff(my_menu_win,COLOR_PAIR(6));
        wrefresh(my_menu_win);
        refresh();
        
        screenTime(3);
        endwin();
        return;
    }
    
    /* Create menu items */
    int tot = 0;
    int q = 0;
        my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(n_choices,sizeof(ITEM *));
    for (int i = 0; i < CONSUMABLESMAX +1; i++) {
        if (tot < n_choices) {
            Consumable * c = &consumablesBag[i];
            q = c->qty;
            if ( q > 0) {
                char qty[15];
                sprintf(qty, "x%i", q);
                    my_items[tot] = new_item(consumablestrings[i], qty);//consumablestrings[i]);
                tot++;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
                
    /* Create menu */
    my_menu = new_menu((ITEM **)my_items);
            
    /* Set description off */
    //menu_opts_off(my_menu,O_SHOWDESC);
```

I tried to debug the array indexing but it seems to work, you have it working on 2 and 4 items... If someone could help I'd greatly appreciate it.

Edit:

After @WeatherVane commented I checked the docs again and in the examples there was always a null pointer ending the items array for the menu, so the crash was resolved by putting
`my_items[tot] = (ITEM*) NULL;`
just before the call to new_menu().

This solves the main problem, but the description string for the menu items is still not correct, as they are all identical, taking the value of the last item on the list. I can't seem to find docs on how this is handled by ncurses, but maybe I should have a separate question for this other problem.

Comment: How does `new_menu(my_items)` know `tot` or `n_choices` the number of items in `my_items`? You haven't done anything with `tot` or placed a sentinel value in the array: although you used `calloc` the array will be full.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with functions you have not shown. There are too many unknowns in the incomplete code posted. Please try to make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. Quite often you can find the problem while doing that.

Comment: @WeatherVane you were correct, the array needed a sentinel value to be correctly handled. No idea why it worked on even numbers (gonna say my enum is only in the single digits, so maybe it's some array allocation doubling sizes and fitting 2 and 4 nicely... I have no idea). Thanks for you help! I understand about the Minimal Reproducible Example and will try to do that for future questions. I still haven't figured out the item description part but this was the main problem. Should I mark this as closed and open a new question? The only code printing that description should be library calls.